# how to get text in between cursor start and end of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

how to get text in between cursor start and end of textarea in html page.

Can someone help me please, i have searched for this but i didnt find any related answers.

any functions like cursor start and cursor end.

can the following could be used

```
var selection = rangy.getSelection(),  // Whole lot of information, supports
                                       // multi-selections too.
    start   = selection.anchorOffset,  // Start position
    end     = selection.focusOffset;   // End position
```

Comment: You can use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) like `str.substring(start, end)`

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vgbhcf4w/2/)

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="tarea"></textarea>
<button id="btn">get text</button>
```

```
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
    cursor = $('#tarea').prop("selectionStart");
    area = $('#tarea');
    console.log(area.val().substring(cursor,area.val().length));
});
```

Comment: it was good but, after clicking the cursor in the textarea only it is getting from that point

Comment: This was because I read your question as *how to get text in between (cursor start) and (end of textarea)*. Do you mean *how to get selected text from textarea?* Can you be more specific?

Comment: not like that as we enter text to text area and clicking on button the text from where it started to that end text has to get

Comment: adding text to text area at the cursor start on button click